# How can I animate a .text change within an on click event?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

So, I'm working on a basic calculator that outputs an incremented variable on click, to a div. Each time a user clicks the 'amount-upwards' button, the 'amount-output' displays a number that's larger by '200'.

Here's the jQuery I'm using to perform that:

```
$(".amount-upwards").on("click",function() {

amount += 200;

$(".amount-output").text('$'+amount);
});
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is add a small fade to that 'amount-output' text, each time the button is clicked.

I've tried variations of fadeIn() and also using a css fade, but, being super new to this, can't quite work out the correct order or method.

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well, so that we can have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".amount-upwards").on("click",function() {

  amount += 200;
  var $amountOutput = $(".amount-output");

  $amountOutput.fadeOut(function(){
    $amountOutput.text('$'+amount)
    $amountOutput.fadeIn()
  });

});
```

Comment: Why? This will fadeOut, put the text then fadeIn